# Jetstream email verification not working, Laravel 10.20.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I had a issue with the SMTP when trying to set up Laravel Jetstream, now I'm able to send e-mails to reset, register.

The problem is, I want to let the user enter the application only if he confirms the e-mail, but when he insert the data to log in, the system sends the e-mail confirmation and log the user in the system.

As the Laravel Jetstream documentation, I uncommented the emailVerification feature in config/fortify.php.

> Features::emailVerification(),

I implemented the MustVerifyEmail interface in App/Models/User.

> use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

and

> class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail

what am I missing?

Comment: just for clarifications, did you run migrations after enabling the feature?

Comment: yeah, it's working, I just can't do this "must verify to login"